# how to add sqlite3.h, sqlite3.dll files in VS2017 in c++ in project directory

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

how to add sqlite3.h, sqlite3.dll files in VS2017 in c++ in project directory

E1696   cannot open source file "sqlite3.h"

Comment: Project Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

Comment: If you have a `sqlite3.dll` you should have an import library `sqlite3.lib` to link with.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the steps below to add .h and dll.

1. Add .h: `Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`
2. Add dll: select `Properties->Build Events->Post-Build Event->Command Line` and input `copy $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)..\..\someFolder\myoutput.dll regasm $(TargetPath)`

If you have the lib, you could refer to the steps below:

Add lib: `Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`

```
    `Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`
```

If you don’t have the lib, you could link explicitly to a DLL.

- Call `LoadLibraryEx` or a similar function to load the DLL and obtain
  a module handle.
- Call `GetProcAddress` to obtain a function pointer to each exported
  function that the application calls. Because applications call the
  DLL functions through a pointer, the compiler doesn't generate
  external references, so there's no need to link with an import
  library. However, you must have a typedef or using statement that
  defines the call signature of the exported functions that you call.
- Call `FreeLibrary` when done with the DLL.

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=vs-2019) for more information.